# Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /media/pc/NameHD: Unknown error occurring when mounting /media/pc/NameHD (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: mount

It is happening with many of my hard disk, all of them 4 Tb, all of a sudden.
I do only have this Ubuntu, so no Windows involved so far. Maybe at their "youth", but I can't recall. The brand of the HDs is Toshiba.
The data are all safe and sound: I checked on a friend's Mac and everything is fine and uncorrputed.
What shall I do without risking to lose my data?

Comment: ? Can you edit your question? https://askubuntu.com/posts/1352708/edit ..... The mount command is missing ......

Comment: I am not using any mount command, just plug the HD in its usb socket on the laptop. Has always worked, now it stopped. I thought it can be due to NTFS formatting, but I have used these HDs for quite a time on Ubuntu - with some hiccup, i must say